# File corrupted while reading record: null - Spring boot java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm doing a simple API, and i'm getting the next error:

> File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-200]

this is the code of the controller that i'm using

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity saveDentist(@RequestBody Dentist data) {
        DentistService dentistService = new DentistService(new DentistDaoH2());
        if(data == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(dentistService.save(data));
    }
```

this is the code of the DAO for the operations of the database(i'm using H2):

```
   @Override
    public Dentist save(Dentist data) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_H2);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASSWORD);
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dentist values(?,?,?,?)");

            preparedStatement.setString(1,data.getName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2,data.getLastName());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,data.getAge());
            preparedStatement.setString(4,data.getProfessionalCard());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            preparedStatement.close();
            System.out.println("its saved");
            logger.info("the user was registered with success");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return data;
    }
```

the code of the service:

```
  public Dentist save(Dentist dentist) {
        if(dentist == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.daoService.save(dentist);
    }
```

the repository layer have the next configuration for h2:

```
 private static final String JDBC_DRIVER_H2 = "org.h2.Driver";
 private final static String USER = "sa";
 private final static String PASSWORD = "";
 private final static String URL = "jdbc:h2:~/test";
```

In the file application.properties have :

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:~/test 
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled = true
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1825

Comment: Why are you using JDBC in spring-boot ?